# Double integral does not exist

Tags: integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to prove that the integral $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}|\exp(\frac{-(x^2+y^2)}2) \, dx \otimes \, dy$$ does not converge.

I transformed into polar coordinates, with $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and $x=r\cos(\phi)$, $y=r\sin(\phi)$ and it became

$$\int_{[0, 2\pi) \times (0,\infty)}|\frac{r^2\sin(\phi)\cos(\phi)}{r^4}|\exp\Big(\frac{-r^2}{2}\Big) \, d\phi \otimes \, dr=$$

$$\int_{[0, 2\pi) \times (0,\infty)}|\frac{\sin(\phi)\cos(\phi)}{r^2}|\exp\Big(\frac{-r^2}{2}\Big) \, d\phi \otimes \, dr=$$

Using double angle formula and then grouping variables together

$$\int_{[0, 2\pi) \times (0,\infty)}|\frac{\sin(2\phi)}{2r^2}|\exp\Big(\frac{-r^2}{2}\Big) \, d\phi \otimes \, dr=\int_{[0, 2\pi) \times (0,\infty)}\frac{\exp(\frac{-r^2}{2})}{2r^2}|\sin(2\phi)| \, d\phi \otimes \, dr=$$

Transforming $r^2$ by $r^2=t$ and then using $1+x \leq \exp(x)$

$$\int_{[0, 2\pi) \times (0,\infty)}\frac{\exp(\frac{-t}{2})}{2t}|\sin(2\phi)| \, d\phi \otimes \, dt \geq \int_{[0, 2\pi) \times (0,\infty)}\frac{1-\frac{t}{2}}{2t}|\sin(2\phi)| \, d\phi \otimes \, dt=$$

$$\int_{[0, 2\pi) \times (0,\infty)}\frac{2-t}{4t} \, |\sin(2\phi)| \, d\phi \otimes \, dt$$

I feel like this function is simpler than at the start, however I fail to see why this integral does not converge. Any hints are welcome.

Comment: Ignore the exponential, and examine the behavior near $r = 0$, that is the oly place where the divergence could occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note
$$\int_{[0, 2\pi) \times (0,\infty)}|\frac{\sin(2\phi)}{2r^2}|\exp\Big(\frac{-r^2}{2}\Big) \, d\phi \otimes \, dr=\int_{[0, 2\pi)}|\sin(2\phi)| \, d\phi \int_{(0,\infty)}\frac{\exp(\frac{-r^2}{2})}{2r^2}\, dr. \tag1$$
But
$$\int_{[0, 2\pi)}|\sin(2\phi)| \, d\phi=const. $$
and
$$\int_{(0,\infty)}\frac{\exp(\frac{-r^2}{2})}{2r^2}\, dr=\int_{(0,1)}\frac{\exp(\frac{-r^2}{2})}{2r^2}\, dr+\int_{(1,\infty)}\frac{\exp(\frac{-r^2}{2})}{2r^2}\, dr.$$
Note the second integral converges and the second one diverges and so (1) diverges. This is because
$$ \frac{\exp(\frac{-r^2}{2})}{2r^2} \ge e^{-\frac12} \frac{1}{2r^2}$$
and $\int_0^1\frac{1}{2r^2}dr$ diverges and hence
$$ \int_{(0,1)}\frac{\exp(\frac{-r^2}{2})}{2r^2}\,dr $$
diverges.

Comment: Two questions: Why are we allowed to iterate the integrals (the whole point of this exercise is that if the integrals are iterated at the start, they both are finite and equal, but the double integral does not converge), and how do you know the last integral diverges? Today is the first time I saw this integral and it is only defined as the function with derivative $\exp(-x)/x$

Comment: What do you mean "iterate the integral"?

Comment: In your first step you have "split" the integrals, and made one over $r$ and one over $\phi$

Comment: Use the property $$ \int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^cf(x)dx+\int_c^bf(x)dx.$$

Comment: That is clear. I ment this step $\int_{[0, 2\pi) \times (0,\infty)}|\frac{\sin(2\phi)}{2r^2}|\exp\Big(\frac{-r^2}{2}\Big) \, d\phi \otimes \, dr=\int_{[0, 2\pi)}|\sin(2\phi)| \, d\phi \int_{(0,\infty)}\frac{\exp(\frac{-r^2}{2})}{2r^2}\, dr.$. 
If I understand correctly, you first calculate the integral over the $\sin$, and then another. But why is this allowed? If we did the same at the start and first calculate the integral over $x$ and then over $y$, we would get $0$

Comment: This is because $\sin(2\phi)$ and $\frac{\exp(-\frac{r^2}{2})}{2r^2}$ are independ each other,